# Widget function does not work in Column widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am building an MusicPlayer app So I need to view list of musicTiles so user can select song from internal storage and play it. So I used File_Picker in appbar through add button from which user can pick up music from their local storage. So I used async and await keyword in my file_picking function. and i store the file_path and file_names in the List type of variables. After that I used my _buidMusicTile() function in my column widget but it flutter gives following Error :

**=>** **type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'**

Code :

```dart
class _MusicPageState extends State<MusicPage> {
  
  FileType _pickingType = FileType.any;
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  List<String> listofAudioFilesPath;
  List<String> listofAudioNames;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() => _extension = _controller.text);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //const Key centerKey = ValueKey('bottom-sliver-list');
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[300],
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Container(
            width: size.width,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.sort),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // _openFileExplorer();
                      FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform
                          .pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);
                      if (result != null) {
                        listofAudioFilesPath = result.paths.toList();

                        listofAudioNames = result.names.toList();

                        print(listofAudioNames);
                        print(listofAudioFilesPath);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Music Library'),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Stack(
            children: [
              _buildMusicTile(listofAudioFilesPath, listofAudioNames),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

_buildMusicTile(
    List<String> listofAudioFilesPath, List<String> listofAudioNames) async {
  List<String> listOfPath = await listofAudioFilesPath;
  List<String> listOfFiles = await listofAudioFilesPath;
  if (listofAudioFilesPath != null && listofAudioNames != null) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: listofAudioNames.length,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: 10,
          color: Colors.white,
        );
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled),
          title: Text(
            '$listofAudioNames[$index]',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  } else {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            '$listofAudioNames',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
          ),
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try use `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `await` inside the body or method which called from the body because that need to render on the screen, UI cannot wait for any data, we need to update that.

**Solution:**

Just remove `await` and `async` from method `_buildMusicTile` like

```
  List<String> listOfPath = listofAudioFilesPath;
  List<String> listOfFiles = listofAudioFilesPath;
```

And add `setState()` inside `onPressed()`

```
setState(() {
        print(listofAudioNames);
        print(listofAudioFilesPath);
  });
```

Comment: Brother It gives same error still  : The following _TypeError was thrown building MudicPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MusicPageState#1cfac):
**type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'**

Comment: Also, remove the async keyword from _buildMusicTile()

Comment: Thanks brother for help.